# Graphs not appearing on my Rshiny Dasboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am a beginner coder and am working on a Rshiny Dashboard for the Rdata "BOD". Unfortunatley, non of my graphs are showing up on the Dashboard. I was wondering what mistakes i have made in my script as no errors are returned if I run the code.

This is my first post on stack overflow so I appologise if I haven't followed proper etiquette.

Thanks,

My Code:

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(forecast)
library(fpp)
library(tsbox)
library(hrbrthemes)

#Data preperation

data(BOD)

summary(BOD)

BODFrame <- data.frame(BOD)

Time <- BODFrame$Time

Demand <- BODFrame$demand

tsdata <- ts(BODFrame, frequency = 2)

ddata <- decompose(tsdata, "multiplicative")

plot(ddata)

seasonal <- (ddata$seasonal)

trend <- (ddata$trend)

random <- (ddata$random)

plot(seasonal)
plot(trend)
plot(random)

forecastframe <- auto.arima(BODFrame[,1])
myforecastframe <- forecast(forecastframe, level=c(60), h = 12)
plot(myforecastframe)

#creating UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Effect of Time on BOD (mg/1) Levels"),
  navbarPage("Select Tab",
             
             tabPanel("Explore The Data",
                      mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Line Graph", plotOutput("line"), br(), radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type", c("png", "jpeg")), downloadButton("dwd", "Download Graph")),
                            tabPanel("Histogram", plotOutput("hist"), br(), radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type", c("png", "jpeg")), downloadButton("dwd", "Download Graph"))
                          )
                        )
                      ),
             
             tabPanel("Stastical Decomposition of the Data",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                     
                                     selectInput(inputId = "Models",
                                                 label = "Select Model:",
                                                 choices = c("Trend"=1, "Seasonality"=2, "Noise"=3),
                                                 selected = 1),
                                     
                                     textOutput("text1")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotOutput("plot2"),
                          br(), radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type", c("png", "jpeg")), downloadButton("dwd", "Download Graph")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Forecasting BOD",
                      mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("Forecast"),
                        br(), radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type", c("png", "jpeg")), downloadButton("dwd", "Download Graph")
                      )
             )
  )
)

#Writing Server Logic

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(BODFrame, aes(x = Time, y = Demand)) + geom_line(col = "cadetblue4", size = 2) + theme_ipsum() + ggtitle("BOD (mg/1) vs Time") +
      geom_point(col = "red", size = 3)
  })
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = BODFrame) + geom_histogram(bins = 6, breaks = c(1:7), mapping = aes(x = Time, y = ..Demand..),
                                             col = "cadetblue4") + theme_ipsum() + ggtitle("BOD (mg/1) vs Time Histogram")
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    if (input$Models == 1){
      plot(trend, main = "Decomposed Trend - BOD")
    }
    else if (input$Models == 2){
      plot(seasonal, main = "Decomposed Seasonality - BOD")
    }
    else if (input$Models == 3){
      plot(random, main = "Decomposed Noise - BOD")
    }
  })
  output$Forecast <- renderPlot({
    plot(myforecastframe, main = "Forecasted Level of BOD (mg/1)")
  })
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    if (input$Models == 1){
      paste0("The increasing or decreasing value of BOD in the series")
    }
    else if (input$Models == 2){
      paste0("The repeating short term cycle of the BOD series.")
    }
    else if (input$Models == 3){
      paste0("The random variation in the BOD series.")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you sure tabPanel and mainPanel are meant to be used like that? I was under the impression that you create a tabset panel _within_ the main panel, like here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tabPanel.html

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was that I was referencing the same input ID multiple times in the UI. E.g. I referenced "filetype" multiple times for my radio buttons. By calling each one a differnt inputID the code worked.